# Wifi Disconnects automatically in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and the only issue i am facing is that wifi automatically disconnects. I have googled many solution snad tried them. I have updated my system and also reinstalled it however i cannot find any fix. I have also installed WCID and then tried it, the problem still remained.
Any help is appreciable.

Outputs:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci

iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp9s0f0  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"VIT2.4G"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:23:68:7D:74:C1
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4797  Invalid misc:15265   Missed beacon:0

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

Well after using sudo iwconfig wlp9s0f0 power off the wifi worked fine for a while and then suddenly it went off. The signal was gone and it showed that wifi device not ready as a message. I ran the above commands but output was same. To fixed it i booted it several times. Then it fixed somehow however now also it keeps on disconnecting, that is net connection breaks. Sometimes it shows that wifi is connected but cant even load google/ bing. To fix that i disable networking only to enable it. PS i have double checked, there is no problem in hardware

Comment: You could not try any solutions if you don't know which wireless adapter you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Also include results for `iwconfig`

Comment: `sudo iwconfig wlp9s0f0 power off` see if that makes any difference

Comment: Up! Same problem here. With the same adapter. Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]

Comment: i have fixed it now.
reinstall  it multiple times is what i did